# pandas groupby with a conditional

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this:

```
IDS    CR_EARNED    TYPE    TOT_ALL_TYPES
001       3          A          7
001       3          A          7
001       1          B          7
002       3          A          6
002       3          A          6
003       2          C          8
003       4          C          8
003       2          A          8
```

TOT_ALL_TYPES is a column I created to sum all TYPE of CR_EARNED for each ID by doing the following:

```
df['TOT_ALL_TYPES'] = df['CR_EARNED'].groupby(df['IDS']).transform('sum')
```

Next, I want to create an new column that will sum CR_EARNED by ID where TYPE = A or B. The result would look like this:

```
IDS    CR_EARNED    TYPE    TOT_ALL_TYPES    TOT_AB
001       3          A          7               7
001       3          A          7               7
001       1          B          7               7
002       3          C          6               3
002       3          A          6               3
003       2          C          8               2
003       4          C          8               2
003       2          A          8               2
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

You can using `where`

```
df['CR_EARNED'].where(df.TYPE.isin(['A','B']),0).groupby(df['IDS']).transform('sum')
Out[887]: 
0    7
1    7
2    7
3    6
4    6
5    2
6    2
7    2
Name: CR_EARNED, dtype: int64
```

More info

```
df['CR_EARNED'].where(df.TYPE.isin(['A','B']),0)
Out[890]: 
0    3
1    3
2    1
3    3
4    3
5    0
6    0
7    2
Name: CR_EARNED, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df['TOT_AB'] = df['IDS'].map(df[df['TYPE'].isin(['A', 'B'])].groupby('IDS').CR_EARNED.sum())


    IDS CR_EARNED   TYPE    TOT_ALL_TYPES   TOT_AB
0   1   3           A       7               7
1   1   3           A       7               7
2   1   1           B       7               7
3   2   3           A       6               6
4   2   3           A       6               6
5   3   2           C       8               2
6   3   4           C       8               2
7   3   2           A       8               2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount` + `np.where`
*Drop the `astype(int)` if it isn't needed*

```
t = np.in1d(df.TYPE.values, ['A', 'B'])
c = df.CR_EARNED.values
f, u = pd.factorize(df.IDS.values)
df.assign(TOT_AB=np.bincount(f, np.where(t, c, 0))[f].astype(int))

   IDS  CR_EARNED TYPE  TOT_ALL_TYPES  TOT_AB
0    1          3    A              7       7
1    1          3    A              7       7
2    1          1    B              7       7
3    2          3    A              6       6
4    2          3    A              6       6
5    3          2    C              8       2
6    3          4    C              8       2
7    3          2    A              8       2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to do multiple variations of these conditional sums, it might be clearer to construct an intermediate pivot table first, then assign based on summing the pivot table.

```
# Set IDS as the index, and construct an intermediate pivot table
df = df.set_index('IDS')
totals_by_type = df.pivot_table(index='IDS', columns='TYPE', values='CR_EARNED',
                                aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

# Get total aggregates
df['TOT_ALL_TYPES'] = totals_by_type.sum(axis=1)
df['TOT_AB'] = totals_by_type[['A', 'B']].sum(axis=1)
```

You can use `reset_index` at the end of this process if you want `'IDS'` to be a column again.

Might not be the best solution if you have a massive amount of data and want to preserve memory though, since you need an intermediate table, but it's more readable and straightforward IMO if this isn't an issue.

The resulting output:

```
     CR_EARNED TYPE  TOT_ALL_TYPES  TOT_AB
IDS                                       
001          3    A              7       7
001          3    A              7       7
001          1    B              7       7
002          3    A              6       6
002          3    A              6       6
003          2    C              8       2
003          4    C              8       2
003          2    A              8       2
```